# Plotting data on MOSI pin

Tags: plot, arduino, signal-processing, esp32, spi

I tested the web radio implementation on VS1053 connected to ESP32. I receive the signals and channel is captured. Now I want to plot real time data on MOSI pin of ESP32 using python. How can I plot the data on MOSI ?

Wiring:

| VS1053 | ESP32 |
| --- | --- |
| SCK | IO18 |
| MISO | IO19 |
| MOSI | IO23 |
| XRST | EN |
| CS | IO5 |
| DCS | IO16 |
| DREQ | IO4 |
| 5V | 5V |
| GND | GND |

This is my code

```c
void setup() {
    Serial.begin(115200);
    SPI.begin();
    player.begin();
    player.switchToMp3Mode();
    player.setVolume(VOLUME);

    if (!client.connect(host, httpPort)) {
        Serial.println("Connection failed");
        return;
    }
    Serial.println(path);
}

void loop() {
    if (!client.connected()) {
        Serial.println("Reconnecting...");
        if (client.connect(host, httpPort)) {
            client.print(String("GET ") + path + " HTTP/1.1\r\n" +
                         "Host: " + host + "\r\n" +
                         "Connection: close\r\n\r\n");
        }
       
    }

    if (client.available() > 0) {
       uint8_t bytesread = client.read(mp3buff, 64);
        player.playChunk(mp3buff, bytesread);  
   }
}

void station_connect () {
    if (client.connect(host,httpPort)) 
        Serial.print(host);
    Serial.println(path);
}
```

Comment: plot where how? there's like 2 million ways to "plot"  if you want to see the signal over time I suggest you get an oscilloscope or a logic analyzer. otherwise you'll have to store the data or send the data somewhere and then plot it somehow. this is way too broad. please read [ask]

Comment: The way I want to plot the graph is using python. Get the reading from MOSI and plot real time data.

Comment: Still don't understand the question, there is one operation to do on the SPI-bus it is WriteRead - where data is written to the slave on MOSI and something is read back on MISO (the rest is "only" clocking and phases)